# How to trigger Button C#

Tags: c#, forms, button, triggers

This is the terms form code:
When form pops up there is one choice that accept button;
How can i click accept from the source code
I just know i need to use somethıng like trigger but how?
If you could help would be very happy

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Honeygain.Presenters;
using Honeygain.Views.Controls;
using Honeygain.Views.Events;

namespace Honeygain.Views.Forms
{
    // Token: 0x02000011 RID: 17
    internal class TermsForm : BaseForm
    {
        // Token: 0x1400001F RID: 31
        // (add) Token: 0x060000EB RID: 235 RVA: 0x00007DE0 File Offset: 0x00005FE0
        // (remove) Token: 0x060000EC RID: 236 RVA: 0x00007E18 File Offset: 0x00006018
        public event EventHandler<FormFailedEventArgs> TermsFailed;

        // Token: 0x14000020 RID: 32
        // (add) Token: 0x060000ED RID: 237 RVA: 0x00007E50 File Offset: 0x00006050
        // (remove) Token: 0x060000EE RID: 238 RVA: 0x00007E88 File Offset: 0x00006088
        public event EventHandler TermsRejected;

        // Token: 0x060000EF RID: 239 RVA: 0x00002A43 File Offset: 0x00000C43
        public TermsForm(IMainPresenter presenter)
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            this._presenter = presenter;
        }

        // Token: 0x060000F0 RID: 240 RVA: 0x00002A58 File Offset: 0x00000C58
        public void CloseTerms()
        {
            CancellationTokenSource actionCTS = this._actionCTS;
            if (actionCTS != null)
            {
                actionCTS.Cancel();
            }
            this._actionCTS = null;
            this._vid = null;
            base.Hide();
        }

        // Token: 0x060000F1 RID: 241 RVA: 0x00007EC0 File Offset: 0x000060C0
        public void ShowTerms(string text, string version, string vid)
        {
            if (!base.Visible)
            {
                CancellationTokenSource actionCTS = this._actionCTS;
                if (actionCTS != null)
                {
                    actionCTS.Cancel();
                }
                this._actionCTS = new CancellationTokenSource();
                this.body.DocumentText = text;
                this._version = version;
                this._vid = vid;
                base.ShowCenter();
            }
        }

        // Token: 0x060000F2 RID: 242 RVA: 0x00002A7F File Offset: 0x00000C7F
        private void OnFormVisibleChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!base.Visible)
            {
                this.Reject();
            }
        }

        // Token: 0x060000F3 RID: 243 RVA: 0x00007F14 File Offset: 0x00006114
        private void OnAcceptClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            TermsForm.<OnAcceptClick>d__14 <OnAcceptClick>d__;
            <OnAcceptClick>d__.<>4__this = this;
            <OnAcceptClick>d__.<>t__builder = AsyncVoidMethodBuilder.Create();
            <OnAcceptClick>d__.<>1__state = -1;
            <OnAcceptClick>d__.<>t__builder.Start<TermsForm.<OnAcceptClick>d__14>(ref <OnAcceptClick>d__);
        }

        // Token: 0x060000F4 RID: 244 RVA: 0x00002A8F File Offset: 0x00000C8F
        private void Reject()
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(this._vid))
            {
                EventHandler termsRejected = this.TermsRejected;
                if (termsRejected != null)
                {
                    termsRejected(this, EventArgs.Empty);
                }
            }
            this.CloseTerms();
        }

        // Token: 0x060000F5 RID: 245 RVA: 0x00007F4C File Offset: 0x0000614C
        private Task Accept()
        {
            TermsForm.<Accept>d__16 <Accept>d__;
            <Accept>d__.<>4__this = this;
            <Accept>d__.<>t__builder = AsyncTaskMethodBuilder.Create();
            <Accept>d__.<>1__state = -1;
            <Accept>d__.<>t__builder.Start<TermsForm.<Accept>d__16>(ref <Accept>d__);
            return <Accept>d__.<>t__builder.Task;
        }

        // Token: 0x060000F6 RID: 246 RVA: 0x00002ABB File Offset: 0x00000CBB
        private void Prepare()
        {
            base.Enabled = false;
        }

        // Token: 0x060000F7 RID: 247 RVA: 0x00002AC4 File Offset: 0x00000CC4
        private void Finish()
        {
            base.Enabled = true;
        }

        // Token: 0x060000F8 RID: 248 RVA: 0x00002ACD File Offset: 0x00000CCD
        private void Fail(Exception exception)
        {
            EventHandler<FormFailedEventArgs> termsFailed = this.TermsFailed;
            if (termsFailed != null)
            {
                termsFailed(this, new FormFailedEventArgs
                {
                    Error = exception
                });
            }
            this.CloseTerms();
        }

        // Token: 0x060000F9 RID: 249 RVA: 0x00002AF3 File Offset: 0x00000CF3
        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing && this.components != null)
            {
                this.components.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        // Token: 0x060000FA RID: 250 RVA: 0x00007F90 File Offset: 0x00006190
        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.components = new Container();
            ComponentResourceManager componentResourceManager = new ComponentResourceManager(typeof(TermsForm));
            this.panel = new TableLayoutPanel();
            this.body = new TermsBrowser(this.components);
            this.accept = new Button();
            this.title = new Label();
            this.panel.SuspendLayout();
            base.SuspendLayout();
            componentResourceManager.ApplyResources(this.panel, "panel");
            this.panel.Controls.Add(this.body, 0, 1);
            this.panel.Controls.Add(this.accept, 0, 2);
            this.panel.Controls.Add(this.title, 0, 0);
            this.panel.Name = "panel";
            componentResourceManager.ApplyResources(this.body, "body");
            this.body.IsWebBrowserContextMenuEnabled = false;
            this.body.Name = "body";
            this.body.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true;
            this.body.WebBrowserShortcutsEnabled = false;
            componentResourceManager.ApplyResources(this.accept, "accept");
            this.accept.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(11, 152, 222);
            this.accept.ForeColor = Color.White;
            this.accept.Name = "accept";
            this.accept.UseVisualStyleBackColor = false;
            this.accept.Click += this.OnAcceptClick;
            componentResourceManager.ApplyResources(this.title, "title");
            this.title.ForeColor = Color.FromArgb(14, 65, 88);
            this.title.Name = "title";
            componentResourceManager.ApplyResources(this, "$this");
            base.Controls.Add(this.panel);
            base.Name = "TermsForm";
            base.VisibleChanged += this.OnFormVisibleChanged;
            this.panel.ResumeLayout(false);
            this.panel.PerformLayout();
            base.ResumeLayout(false);
            base.PerformLayout();
        }

        // Token: 0x0400006D RID: 109
        private readonly IMainPresenter _presenter;

        // Token: 0x0400006E RID: 110
        private string _version;

        // Token: 0x0400006F RID: 111
        private string _vid;

        // Token: 0x04000070 RID: 112
        private CancellationTokenSource _actionCTS;

        // Token: 0x04000073 RID: 115
        private IContainer components;

        // Token: 0x04000074 RID: 116
        private TableLayoutPanel panel;

        // Token: 0x04000075 RID: 117
        private TermsBrowser body;

        // Token: 0x04000076 RID: 118
        private Button accept;

        // Token: 0x04000077 RID: 119
        private Label title;
    }
}
```

This is the terms form code:
When form pops up there is one choice that accept button;
How can i click accept from the source code
I just know i need to use somethıng like trigger but how?
If you could help would be very happy

Comment: Event trigger is already implemented you just need register your event to button accept Click   delegate and it will be triggered on click, But if you need to perform click from code try check for method PerformClick  or  just call  accept.Click.Invoke(//params//)

Comment: How can i use perform click in this code,sory im very very new